# JSON Array to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, json

*JSON* Array:

```
[ { sw: 'NODE.JS' }, { sw: 'Heroku Toolbelt' } ]
```

need to convert it to:

```
['NODE.JS','Heroku Toolbelt'].
```

Any quickest help will be highly apprecaited.

Comment: JSON is a string. "JSON Array" is not a thing. What you have is an array of objects, that you want to convert to an array based on a property of those objects.

Comment: What's the problem? You don't know how to use a `for` loop? or you don't know how to add items to a new Array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript array of objects, extract value of a property as array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/javascript-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var new_array = arr.map(function(e) {
    return e.sw;
});
```

Don't forget to get the actual JavaScript array from the JSON *string* with `JSON.parse` (as an example).